# C++ friend class map

Tags: c++, dictionary, non-static, friend-class

So i have  problem trying to access a friend class properties, i need a pointer to the first item in the map.

class.h

```
class A{

    private:
    map<int,float> database;
    public:
    ......
    class B{
        private:
          map<int,float>::iterator it;
        public:
            friend class A;
            B begin();
    }

}
```

and implem.hxx

```
A::B A::B::begin(){
            A::B it;
            ite.it = database.begin();
            return ite;
}
```

But it shows a problem when compiling:
    error: invalid use of non-static data member A::database

How can i resolve the problem?

Comment: this is not java: `A::B` doesn't have an enclosing creating instance of `A` in C++

Comment: Your example doesn't describe what means `ite` in `ite.it = database.begin();`

Answer (score 1):

Besides some syntax issues, I see the `A::database` variable is attempted to be accessed in `A::B::begin()`. But this variable is not static to access it in that way, and class B is not derived from A as well. So, that the question imho has nothing to do with the friendship.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note is that it is completely redundant to make A a friend of B. **Inner classes in C++ have access to private members of outer classes.** However, when you're creating an instance of B, in there is no **instance** of class A, for which you are trying to access the map. You need an instance.

Answer (score 0):

`A::B` doesn't have an enclosing creating instance of `A` like in Java for example - `begin` needs an object of type `A` to access its `database`:

```
A::B A::B::begin(A& a) {
    A::B b;
    b.it = a.database.begin();
    return b;
}
```

Note that `A::B` doesn't need to declare `A` as `friend` to access private members of `A` (`friend` works the other way around) `B` already has access to the private members since it is nested.

It seems to me you wanted to wrap iterators of `A::database` in `B`, so hopefully this points you in the right direction:

```
class A {
    std::map<int,float> database;

public:
    class B {
        friend class A;
        std::map<int,float>::iterator it;
        explicit B(std::map<int,float>::iterator it) : it(it) { }
        ...
    };

    B begin();
};

A::B A::begin() {
    return B(database.begin());
}
```

Now `begin` is a member function of `A` and creates a `B` using a private constructor only `A` may access. Here's the usage code:

```
A a;
A::B b = a.begin();
...
```

Comment: It says the same. error: invalid use of non-static data member